# Programming a UART for PIC24F, can't write the character into the Transmit Buffer

Tags: uart, pic24fj1024gb610, pic24f

I want to create a simple program that transmits a signal from my UART module of my [PIC24FJ1024GB610](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC24FJ1024GB610) microcontroller from Microchip.

I am using UART1, 8 bits, No parity, and one Stop bit.

According to the [Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC24FJ1024GA610-GB610-Family-Data-Sheet-DS30010074G.pdf) and the [dsPIC33/PIC24 Family Reference Manual, UART](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70000582e.pdf), in order to start a transmission, we should perform the following steps:

---

1. Configure the Clock Signal source (4MHz from FRC)

I would like Fcy = 4MHz, CS is sourced from FRC (Fast Internal RC) which have a frequency of 8MHz, after passing through the postscalar the frequency gets divided by 2. *Section 9.0 of the [Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC24FJ1024GA610-GB610-Family-Data-Sheet-DS30010074G.pdf)*

`#pragma config FNOSC = FRC`

---

2. Configure the Baud Rate Generator Time Period.

   [image]

This formula is from the *[Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC24FJ1024GA610-GB610-Family-Data-Sheet-DS30010074G.pdf), Section 19.1*, I use this formula to get the Baud Rate Generator period (UxBRG). My Fcy = 4MHz, Baud Rate = 9600

U1BRG = ((4000000)/(16*9600)) - 1

`U1BRG = 25`

---

---

3. Configure the UART, I would like the UART data format to have 8 bits, No Parity, and one Stop bit

   ```
   U1MODEbits.PDSEL = 0;//8 bits, No Parity
   U1MODEbits.STSEL = 0;//1 stop bit
   U1MODEbits.UEN = 0;//only use UxRX and UxTX pins
   ```
4. Configure UART TX ISR source, I want a TXIF to be set when a write is performed on UART1 Transmit Buffer (U1TXREG) `U1STAbits.TXISEL0 = 0` `U1STAbits.TXISEL0 = 0`

---

5. Enable the UART `U1MODEbits.UARTEN = 1` and enable the Transmitter `U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1`
6. write a value at the TX Buffer `U1TXREG`

---

As soon as there is a write on the TX Register, the data is transferred to the Transmit Shift Register, and it will stream the data one bit at a time.

In order to ensure a successful transmission at first, there should be a delay between Enabling the UART and writing to Transmit Buffer, the delay = 1/BaudRate, in our case it is 1/9600 = 105 us

Since my application isn't time critical I decided to make a simple for loop as a delay it will count from 0 to 0xFFFE `for(i = 0;i<0xFFFF;++i);`

There is the full code for reference:

```
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF
#pragma config ICS = PGD2

#pragma config FNOSC = FRC

#include "xc.h"

int main(void)
{
    U1BRG = 25;//U1BRG = (4000000)/(16*9600) - 1

    //UART SETUP
    U1MODEbits.PDSEL = 0;//No parity, 8 bits
    U1MODEbits.STSEL = 0;//One Stop Bit
    U1MODEbits.UEN = 0;//only U1TX and U1RX
    U1MODEbits.BRGH = 0;

    U1STAbits.UTXISEL1 = 0;//tx isr when a write occurs to TX BUF
    U1STAbits.UTXISEL0 = 0;

    //U1TX pin
    RPOR5bits.RP10R = 3;//U1TX -> RP10

    U1MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;//enable UART

    U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1;//enable transmission

    unsigned int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 0xFFFF;++i);

    U1TXREG = 'a';


    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

---

When I debug and step into the `U1TXREG = 'a'`, I am supposed to get an 'a' at the `U1TXREG`, but instead, it is 0, I even changed the to a 2 and it is still 0.

[image]

---

I even tried debugging and capturing the UART signal using an oscilloscope, I mapped U1TX pin to a Peripheral Pin Select pin (RP10) which is Pin 49 on my development board (Explorer 16/32), I only see a High State (3.3V) at the pin.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: One thing: Your delay loop may actually be optimized away into nothing by the compiler. You may want to change "unsigned int i" to "volatile unsigned int i".

Comment: Refer to the datasheet, page 263 for the UxTXREG register description.
There you'll find that this register is *Write-Only*. You can't read from it in code, and neither can the debugger.

Comment: @brhans yes I read that it makes sense why I couldn't read the TX BUF. Tried debugging using an oscilloscope, however, I realized I need to do an unlocking sequence in order to configure pins for the PPS

Comment: @Big6 I don't think that was the issue, as I tried using the delay inline function provided by the reference manual, I think the problem was that TX BUF was a write-only register, and I couldn't see the TX on my oscilloscope because I didn't implement an unlock PPS sequence.